# XSLT determine which attribute is repeated the most

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some difficult markup I'm working with that doesn't have normalized IDs in it. Let me show by example of what said markup might look like:

```
<listing>
    <foo fooid="81">Foo</foo>
    <bar barid="88">Bar</bar>
</listing>
<listing>
    <foo fooid="82">Foo</foo>
    <bar barid="81">Bar</bar>
</listing>
<listing>
    <foo fooid="83">Foo</foo>
    <bar barid="81">Bar</bar>
</listing>
```

The ID that I need to be able to stuff into an `<xsl:variable />` in this case is 81 because the id is represented the most amount of times, regardless of its tags. Is there a trivial way to do this with XSLT? Ideally when it's said and done, I'll have something like:

`<xsl:variable name="an_id">` where `an_id` is equal to `81`

The known points are the following:

- the tags are always called foo or bar.
- the attributes are always called fooid or barid
- the number I'm looking to capture in a variable will be listed at least once in either of the two tags
- the number I'm looking to capture will definitely be present at least once in each of the listings.
- The irrelevant numbers may or may not show up more than once.

I am using XSLT 1.0. The variable name is not dynamic. It is static, can be called `whatever` as long as the value it derives to is the 81 above.

** UPDATE **

The XML I pasted above was sample and although I think Mads answer is correct, it doesn't parse so I'm updating with the real XML I'm dealing with. You can see the equivalent in my contrived example that `<foo>` and `<bar>` are trying to tackle the `<hometeam>` and `<awayteam>` tags, those are the key ones to focus in on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<message>
  <XML_File_ID>18996672</XML_File_ID>
  <heading>ABX%PHI-SKED</heading>
  <category>Statistics</category>
  <sport>NFL</sport>
  <title>2013 Philadelphia Eagles Schedule/Results</title>
  <season>2013</season>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4189</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>09/09/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>06:55 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>1</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="081">Philadelphia</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="088">Washington</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>FedEx Field</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>ESPN</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4206</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>09/15/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>01:00 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>2</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="083">San Diego</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="081">Philadelphia</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Lincoln Financial Field</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>CBS</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4253</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>09/19/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>08:25 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>3</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="072">Kansas City</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="081">Philadelphia</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Lincoln Financial Field</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>NFL Network</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4331</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>09/29/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>04:25 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>4</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="081">Philadelphia</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="067">Denver</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Sports Authority Field at Mile High Stadium</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4366</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>10/06/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>01:00 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>5</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="081">Philadelphia</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="079">NY Giants</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>MetLife Stadium</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>True</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4403</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>10/13/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>01:00 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>6</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="081">Philadelphia</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="087">Tampa Bay</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Raymond James Stadium</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4419</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>10/20/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>01:00 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>7</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="066">Dallas</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="081">Philadelphia</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Lincoln Financial Field</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4197</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>10/27/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>01:00 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>8</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="079">NY Giants</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="081">Philadelphia</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Lincoln Financial Field</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4216</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>11/03/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>04:05 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>9</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="081">Philadelphia</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="073">Oakland</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Oakland-Alameda County Coliseum</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4230</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>11/10/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>01:00 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>10</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="081">Philadelphia</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="069">Green Bay</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Lambeau Field</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4251</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>11/17/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>01:00 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>11</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="088">Washington</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="081">Philadelphia</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Lincoln Financial Field</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4302</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>12/01/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>01:00 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>13</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="086">Arizona</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="081">Philadelphia</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Lincoln Financial Field</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4322</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>12/08/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>01:00 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>14</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="068">Detroit</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="081">Philadelphia</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Lincoln Financial Field</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4350</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>12/15/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>01:00 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>15</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="081">Philadelphia</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="076">Minnesota</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Mall of America Field at HHH Metrodome</Location>
    <Indoor>True</Indoor>
    <Turf>True</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4365</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>12/22/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>01:00 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>16</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="063">Chicago</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="081">Philadelphia</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>Lincoln Financial Field</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>False</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <season_type>Regular</season_type>
    <schedule_id>4391</schedule_id>
    <Game_Date>12/29/2013</Game_Date>
    <Game_Time>01:00 PM</Game_Time>
    <week>17</week>
    <ascore>0</ascore>
    <hscore>0</hscore>
    <awayteam awayteamid="081">Philadelphia</awayteam>
    <hometeam hometeamid="066">Dallas</hometeam>
    <TypeUpdate>P</TypeUpdate>
    <Status>
    </Status>
    <Location>AT&amp;T Stadium</Location>
    <Indoor>False</Indoor>
    <Turf>True</Turf>
    <TV_Listing>FOX</TV_Listing>
  </listing>
  <time_stamp> September 3, 2013, at 05:17 PM ET </time_stamp>
</message>
```

Basically I'm trying to get the home team's ID. Since it's not normalized above before the listings, I have to go for the team that's listed in every listing (and thus shows up the most). In this case it would be Philadelphia who has an ID of "081", but once you run `number()` on that in the XSLT processor, it should just be `81`.

Here's the stylesheet I have working so far based on Mads answer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key name="id" match="@awayteamid | @hometeamid" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/message">
    <xsl:variable name="heading"><xsl:value-of select="heading"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="team_id">
      <xsl:for-each select="*/listing/*/@*">
         <xsl:sort select="count(key('id', .))" order="descending" data-type="number" />
         <xsl:if test="position()=1">
             <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:variable>

    {
     "team_id": <xsl:value-of select="number($team_id)" /> 
    }
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And finally the error I'm getting using it (assuming it's because `$team_id` is not properly being set)

```
#<JSON::ParserError: 203: unexpected token at 'NaN 
    }
  '>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? Also please show your expected output for this sample imput. Please show a sample input document (not a non-document fragment as you have shown now).

Comment: what is the xslt processor? do you want variable name to be dynamic or the value?

Comment: Updated question to address the xslt processor and variable naming question.

Comment: Had to update one more time with actual data. Think Mads has the right answer, but I can't get it working against real data and that's my fault.

Comment: You need to adjust the XPath in your for-each to be relative from the context node, which is the `message` element: `<xsl:for-each select="listing/*/@*">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a key that matches on either of those attributes:

```
<xsl:key name="id" match="@fooid | @barid" use="."/>
```

And then create the `an_id` variable who's value is the first item from a sorted list of the attribute values, using the count of items in the key matching the attribute value.

```
<xsl:variable name="an_id">
   <xsl:for-each select="*/listing/*/@*">
       <xsl:sort select="count(key('id', .))" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
       <xsl:if test="position()=1">
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

---

Updated answer using your XML and XSLT (which you almost had, just needed to adjust the XPath in your for-each to account for what the context node is and where you are "standing" when the expression gets evaluated):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="id" match="@awayteamid | @hometeamid" use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/message">
        <xsl:variable name="heading"><xsl:value-of select="heading"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="team_id">
            <xsl:for-each select="listing/*/@*">
                <xsl:sort select="count(key('id', .))" order="descending" data-type="number" />
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        {
        "team_id": <xsl:value-of select="number($team_id)" /> 
        }
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This looks like it's headed in the right direction, but it consistently pulls up the same ID which is the wrong one. It is listed in the document twice, but another one is listed more often. Any advice for debugging?

Comment: Also the IDs are currently padded with a 0 in front of them, will that make a difference? Something along the lines of "088" "077" etc.

Comment: @randombits: If you think it is wrong, show the input and output which proves it wrong. Otherwise your remark is unhelpful. Mad's solution works for the sample data you provided.

Comment: Are they consistently 3 digits, or is it a mixture of 088, 88, 077, 77?  If a mixture, then that would make a difference is they are being treated as strings.

Comment: Really sorry about the confusion. I posted the actual XML I'm dealing with. Hope you can take one more look. I thought by condensing it and putting together a contrived sample, it would save space/time. It actually didn't, though and that's my fault.

Comment: Actually figured it out. This was awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:key name="kFoobars" match="foo/@fooid | bar/@fooid |
                                foo/@barid | bar/@barid" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="foobar-els" select="*/foo | */bar" />
  <xsl:variable name="foobar-atr" select="$foobar-els/@fooid | $foobar-els/@barid" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$foobar-atr[ generate-id() =
                                     generate-id( key('kFoobars',.)[1])]">
    <xsl:sort select="count(key('kFoobars',.))" data-type="number" order="descending" />
    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
      <t most-populous-id-value="{.}" />
    </xsl:if>  
  </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```